# How can I show only the most recent 100 results from the database in the CMS?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I would like to show only the most recently 100 entries in my Database on the CMS side of my silverstripe site. I can currently see all 600 and this is unnecessary. The silverstripe docs are unhelpful and I cant get onto their forum to ask this.

I have tried to set a greater than filter on the ID for the table but the filter isn't working.

This is my Model Admin file

```
use SilverStripe\Admin\ModelAdmin;
use SilverStripe\Forms\DateField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridField;
use UndefinedOffset\SortableGridField\Forms\GridFieldSortableRows;
use SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldFilterHeader;

class BonusAllocations extends ModelAdmin
{

private static $managed_models = [
    'AffiliateProgram\MemberBonus'
];

private static $url_segment = 'bonus';

private static $menu_title = 'Bonuses Allocations';

public function getList()
{
    $list = parent::getList();

    return $list;
}

}
```

And this is my current dataObject

```
<?php
namespace AffiliateProgram;

use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\DropdownField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridField;
use UndefinedOffset\SortableGridField\Forms\GridFieldSortableRows;
use SilverStripe\Security\Permission;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;


class MemberBonus extends DataObject
{
private static $db = [
    'Amount' => 'Currency',
    'Confirmed' => 'Boolean',
    'Level' => 'Int',
    'Percentage' => 'Int'
];

private static $has_one = [
    'Member' => 'AffiliateProgram\Member',
    'MemberPayment' => 'AffiliateProgram\MemberPayment',
    'PaymentType' => 'AffiliateProgram\PaymentType',
    'ProgramType' => 'AffiliateProgram\ProgramType'
];

private static $summary_fields = [
    'Amount' => 'Amount (USD)',
    'Member.Email' => 'Email', 
    'Level',
    'MemberPayment.PaymentType.Symbol' => 'Recieved As',
    'Percentage' => 'Percentage Bonus Applied',
    'ProgramType.Name' => 'Program Type',
    'MemberPayment.Created' => 'Payment Date',
    // 'Confirmed' => 'Confirmed?',
    'MemberPayment.ID' => 'Payment ID',
    'ID' => 'Bonus ID'
];


public function searchableFields()
{
    return [
        'Member.Email' => [
            'filter' => 'PartialMatchFilter',
            'title' => 'Email',
            'field' => TextField::class,
        ],
        'ProgramType.Name' => [
            'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter',
            'title' => 'Program',
            'field' => DropdownField::create('ProgramType')
                ->setSource(
                    ProgramType::get()->map('Name','Name')
                )
                ->setEmptyString('-- Any Program --')                
        ],
        'MemberPayment.PaymentType.Symbol' => [
            'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter',
            'title' => 'Locale (Symbol)'              
        ],
    ];
}
  }
```

Comment: `$list = $list->limit(100);`

Comment: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/#limit

Comment: @3dgoo sorry to be a pain but could you show me where exactly to implement this? Would this be in the modelAdmin before returning list? Cheers!

Comment: Edit: I did the above and it changes the 'view 1-100 or 100' at the top but doesnt effect the number of entries that are displayed... any ideas?

Comment: By default ModelAdmin's gridfield paginates and shows 15 entries per page. Did you do anything special in your ModelAdmins's EditForm method?

Answer (score 2):

In SilverStripe 4 to limit a list in our custom `ModelAdmin` we can define a `getList` function and modify the list as needed.

Here is an example of a custom `ModelAdmin` where we call the `DataList` [`limit()`](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/#limit) function to limit the entries to a maximum of 100 items.

```
use SilverStripe\Admin\ModelAdmin;

class BonusAllocations extends ModelAdmin
{

    private static $managed_models = [
        'AffiliateProgram\MemberBonus'
    ];

    private static $url_segment = 'bonus';

    private static $menu_title = 'Bonuses Allocations';

    public function getList()
    {
        $list = parent::getList();

        $list = $list->limit(100);

        return $list;
    }

}
```